# ObjectOutputStream.readInt() throws EOFException even if there is still data in file

Tags: java, exception

We have a problem in our application which can be reduced to this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        File tempFile = File.createTempFile("teststream", "");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeInt(1);
        oos.writeObject("foo");
        oos.writeInt(2);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        int n1 = ois.readInt();
        Object o1 = ois.readObject();
        int n2 = ois.readInt();
    }
```

This code works, although if you comment the following line:

```
Object o1 = ois.readObject();
```

The following line

```
int n2 = ois.readInt();
```

will throw an `EOFException` although there is data in my file since I wrote an object and an integer in it. The [javadoc of readInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readInt%28%29) does not indicate this behavior. I'm a little bit worried about this `EOFException`, since we would like to distinguish in our code between a real *there is nothing more to read in your file* exception and a *wrong type of content* one.

The stack trace for the exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2793)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:968)
```

Which means the following code in `DataInputStream` throws the exception:

```
 public final int readInt() throws IOException {
        int ch1 = in.read();
        int ch2 = in.read();
        int ch3 = in.read();
        int ch4 = in.read();
        if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
            throw new EOFException();
```

But `in.read()` is not supposed to return a negative number when there is data in the input stream so I'm really intrigued.

Is there something that can be done in my code to prevent this from happening (knowing that we might at some point call `readInd` where `writeObject` was used)?

I am using this version of java:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.2) (ArchLinux build 7.u7_2.3.2-2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: no, this is done by oos.close() and is not related to the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying stream is written in blocks, with block headers.  When you attempt to `readInt` when an object was written the wrong block type is found and the `in.read()` returns -1.

The following method is called.

```
    /**
     * Attempts to read in the next block data header (if any).  If
     * canBlock is false and a full header cannot be read without possibly
     * blocking, returns HEADER_BLOCKED, else if the next element in the
     * stream is a block data header, returns the block data length
     * specified by the header, else returns -1.
     */
    private int readBlockHeader(boolean canBlock) throws IOException {
         // code deleted
                int tc = in.peek();
                switch (tc) {
                    case TC_BLOCKDATA:
         // code deleted
                    default:
                        if (tc >= 0 && (tc < TC_BASE || tc > TC_MAX)) {
                            throw new StreamCorruptedException(
                                String.format("invalid type code: %02X",
                                tc));
                        }
                        return -1;
    }
```

The -1 means the end has been reached when a `StreamCorruptedException` might have been a better choice here.

Comment: @EJP Coming from you, that is a complement. ;)

Comment: ok well then I guess there is no way for me to get this StreamCorruptedException for this case as I would have preferred. I'll fill a feature request if I'm motivated enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you comment the line, `Object o1 = ois.readObject();`, and you execute your program, `n2` is not reading an `int`, instead it's reading 4 characters from the Serialized Object. Yes, you can get a negative value, depending on how the object were serialized (e.g. the endianness of the object stored, which, if memory serves me correctly, are stored in Big-Endian).

Comment: but the documentation of InputStream.read() states that it returns an int in the range 0 to 255, since it reads a byte. I don't see where endianness changes anything if it treats the byte as unsigned there is no way it returns a negative value.

Comment: Yes, `readInt()` logical ORs 4 bytes. The new field becomes a 32 bit int, and you can represent a negative value on a 32 bit int.

Answer (score 1):

The situation is completely invalid. If you don't read what you wrote, the behaviour is undefined. It probably shouldn't throw an `EOFException` in this circumstance, but as you can't point to a specification that says what it should do when you do the wrong thing, you don't really have a leg to stand on.

Comment: I don't really understand the "the situation is completely invalid", for me a situation can either occur or not. I agree with the rest, I could not find anything about the expected behaviour in my case so I cannot expect anything but that's a lack of feature in my point of view. Other parts of the standard lib have a lot better error handling and Peter Lawrey investigations tell me it was doable to handle this case in this implementation.

Comment: @jolivier What integer value are you expecting to read when the next thing in the stream isn't an int but an object?

Comment: i'm expecting a `StreamCorruptedException` either when reading the int or reading the next type that cannot be read because the byte data in the file can not be converted.