# Why do I get EOF exception while reading a datainputstream in java?

Tags: java

Here is what I am trying to read :

```
   FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("count.txt");
   BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(fis);
   DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(bis);
   while(dis.read()!=-1)
   {
    orderCount=dis.readInt();
    newOrderCount=dis.readInt();
   }
```

Count.txt has data such  as 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, but for some reason i get an EOF exception,please help!

Comment: Because you're doing two reads within the same loop cycle...

Comment: no ,i just remove one of the int still the same

Comment: One read per cycle works for me..

Comment: Check this post, this addresses your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598190/objectoutputstream-readint-throws-eofexception-even-if-there-is-still-data-in

Comment: Actually, you're doing 3 reads per cycle...

Answer (score 0):

`EOFException` means you tried to read past the end of the stream, which probably happened because you are reading a byte and then throwing it away, which is already a bug, as it puts you out of sync with the sender. Change the loop test to `while (true)`, catch `EOFException`, and, when you get it, close the socket and break out of the loop.